# malloc() deja bytes vacíos entre medias al guardar char*

Tags: c, ram, heap

Antes que nada, soy bastante nuevo en C, pero en un tutorial en internet vi un ejercicio para manejo del *heap* que me interesó programar en mi máquina.

He aquí el código que reserva y escribe en el *heap*:

```
char* texter = "Muestra para StackOverflow";

int *i = (char*)malloc(1024);   
for (int a = 0; a < strlen(texter); a++) {
    i[a] = texter[a];
}
```

Partiendo de que todo va bien y de que el texto se escribe en la memoria, según he visto por ese tutorial, el texto *x* justo antes de `malloc()` le debería decir que separe en bloques del tamaño de *x* a la hora de escribir en la memoria.
Aun así, el *dump* de memoria una vez ejecutado el código sería *grosso modo*:

```
 4d 00 00 00 75 00 00 00 65 00 00 00 73 00 00 00 74 00 00 00 72 00 00 00 61 00 00 00...
```

Se puede apreciar cómo entre carácter y carácter están 3 bytes vacíos, significando que cada *término* ocupa cuatro caracteres.
Escribir `char*` antes de `malloc()` no debería evitar los huecos en cero al ajustar el ancho del bloque a un byte, que es justo el ancho de `char*`; y sólo aparecer en esta cantidad si escribo `long*`?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Se puede apreciar cómo entre carácter y carácter están 3 bytes vacíos, significando que cada término ocupa cuatro caracteres.

Has acertado en una cosa y fallado en dos.

---

Has reservado memoria para 1024 caracteres:

```
(char*)malloc(1024)
```

Pero lo has guardado en un puntero a entero:

```
   int *i = (char*)malloc(1024);
// ~~~~~ <--- Puntero (*) a entero (int)
```

Lo que significa que cuando recorres el bucle no lo haces *carácter a carácter* si no que lo haces *entero a entero*:

```
for (int a = 0; a < strlen(texter); a++) {
    i[a] = texter[a];
//  ^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^
//    \         \________ Esto es un carácter (char).
//     \_________________ Esto es un entero (int).
}
```

Por lo tanto, estás guardando en un entero (`int`) el valor de un carácter (`char`). Generalmente los caracteres ocupan un byte (8 bits) y los enteros ocupan cuatro bytes (32 bits)<sup>1</sup>, por lo que cuando muestras la memoria ves que el carácter se ha guardado en el primero de los cuatro bytes que el entero tenía disponible, dejando los otros tres en blanco.

Seguramente querías hacer esto:

```
char* texter = "Muestra para StackOverflow";

   char *i = (char*)malloc(1024);
// ~~~~~~ <--- Puntero a carácter
for (int a = 0; a < strlen(texter); a++) {
    i[a] = texter[a];
}
```

Que sería mejor así:

```
char* texter = "Muestra para StackOverflow";

char *i = (char*)malloc(1024);
   memcpy(i, texter, strlen(texter));
// ~~~~~~ <--- Copiar texter en i
```

O mucho mejor así:

```
char* texter = "Muestra para StackOverflow";

   char i[1024];
// ~~~~~~ <--- No necesitamos memoria dinámica
memcpy(i, texter, strlen(texter));
```

---

1. En arquitecturas de 32 bits.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Lo más doloroso es que en el tutorial sale con char* en el puntero. Vaya vergüenza. Bueno, espero que esto sirva para no hacer más el inútil a tales horizontes en el futuro.

Comment: Me gustaría ver ese tutorial, tal vez en su contexto tenga sentido el código. ¿Dónde puedo verlo?

Comment: Es el tutorial de heap y stack de https://brilliant.org. Simplemente explicaba cómo se usa el heap con C y qué es más teóricamente hablando.
Ahora que lo veo, int* como tipo del puntero se usa cuando se pone int* antes de malloc. Será que me confundí entre varios bloques de distintos ejemplos. Vaya fallo.

Comment: ¿ Porqué muestra `4d 00 00 00` y no `00 00 00 4d` ? ¿ No debería mostrar esto último ?

Comment: @Trauma tratándose de little-endian, no. Empieza a escribir el byte menos significativo, y al no cubrir todo el sitio que tiene, se coloca lo que hay desde ahí.

Comment: @Vyber90 Jejeje ... Ya lo se (mira mi comentario en tu pregunta). Estoy intentando que el Paper lo indique en su respuesta ;-)

Comment: @Trauma ya decía yo. Un poco raro me parecía que un entendido de la materia y encima que habla de esto en la respuesta tuviera tales dudas. Perdona, serán los nervios de mi ignorancia :(

Comment: La pregunta no es sobre la [extremidad](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) de los datos.

Comment: @Vyber90 ¿No tienes el enlace al tutorial de brilliant?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster aquí tiene: https://brilliant.org/practice/the-heap-segment/?p=1